# how to check if file exists in all subdirectories?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

How to check if the file exists in all subdirectories within chef recipe (`not_if` guard).

Comment: I suggest you post an answer and remove the edit to your question and the comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific answer other than "write some Ruby code to check what you want". You'll probably want to do a Dir glob and then compare the various outputs but maybe you just need an `all?` and `File.exist?`.

Comment: Just ended up with `not_if "find . -name *.jar |grep #{git_repo}"`, but, if I was a ruby programmer, I would do as you suggested :)